# JSF 2.2.10 file upload not working

Tags: file-upload, jsf-2.2, jboss6.x

Issue: Action method and setter for file not getting called on file upload.

I did see the link for JSF 2.2 not working, but it is over 4 years old and I thought the problem should have been resolved. I am posting this since I am facing it today!

I am using JSF 2.2.10, JBoss 6.4; I have mojarra set up in JBoss config as follows:  (in  \modules\system\layers\base\org\jboss\weld\core\main and \modules\system\layers\base\org\jboss\as\weld\main)

I have set up my xhtml and Controller as follows. Would greatly appreciate if you could point out what I am missing. Been stuck with this for more than a day now!

```
<h:form id="massUpload" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3">
<h:inputFile id="file" value="#{controller.uploadedFile}" />
<h:commandButton value="Upload"
action="#{controller.massUploadBranchGLInfoViaFile}"/>
</div>
</h:form>
```

Controller As follows:

```
@Named("controller")
@ViewScoped 
public class MyController
    extends AccessController
    implements Serializable
{
private Part uploadedFile;
public String massUploadBranchGLInfoViaFile() throws IOException {
    InputStream stream = uploadedFile.getInputStream();


    addSuccessInfoToFlash("update-gl-success");
    return  "Success";
}

public void setUploadedFile(Part file){
    this.uploadedFile = file;
}

public Part getUploadedFile(){
    return this.uploadedFile;
}
}
```

Thank you very much
Karthik

Comment: I also tried using public void massUpload... - didn't make a difference...

Answer (score 1):

Found (at least part of) the issue: Had to add the multipart-config to servlet configuration in my web.xml. That resolved calling the action and set methods. Am getting a NULLPointerException now. But one issue at a time I guess :)